# Updating property value in properties file without deleting other values

Tags: java, properties

Content of `First.properties`:

```
name=elango
country=india
phone=12345
```

I want change `country` from `india` to `america`. This is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
public class UpdateProperty 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception 
    {   
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("First.properties");
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("First.properties");
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(in);
        in.close();
        props.setProperty("country", "america");
        props.store(out, null);
        out.close();
    } 
}
```

Output content of `First.properties`:

```
country=america
```

The other properties are deleted. I want update a particular property value, without deleting the other properties.

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461901/how-to-overwrite-one-property-in-properties-without-overwriting-the-whole-file and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565932/a-better-class-to-update-property-files

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Open the  output stream and store properties after you have closed the input stream.

```
try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("First.properties")) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(in);
}
        
try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("First.properties"))
    props.setProperty("country", "america");
    props.store(out, null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vasyl Keretsman
i change code.
Is it correct?
 Properties props = new Properties();
                props.load(in);
                props.setProperty("country", "america");
        props.store(out, null);
        out.close();
         in.close();
         
         but answer is same. I didn't get the expected answer

Comment: Not correct. I have added the code to my answer

Comment: Thank You Vasyl Keretsman. It is working ..

Comment: @VasylKeretsman  it is removed all existing comments in  the file

Comment: Closing streams should be done in a finally block/ try-with-resources statement.

Comment: Maybe you are also interested in this Property Library. It can preserve order and comments.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565932/a-better-class-to-update-property-files

Comment: Yes gr8 it solved ......... but why ?????

Comment: How did this become the accepted answer ? It removes all previously set properties.

Comment: This answer should state that you have to rewrite all properties again. Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461901/how-to-overwrite-one-property-in-properties-without-overwriting-the-whole-file

Comment: Those for which the code is not working. Please verify the sequence of lines with the code provided. Sequence of lines does matter here.

Comment: It removes all the previous properties. And aslo adds the timestamp in the first line of the property file.

Answer (score 35):

You can use [Apache Commons Configuration](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/) library.
The best part of this is, it won't even mess up the properties file and keeps it intact ([even comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565932/a-better-class-to-update-property-files/565996#565996)).

[Javadoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration2/PropertiesConfiguration.html)

```
PropertiesConfiguration conf = new PropertiesConfiguration("propFile.properties");
conf.setProperty("key", "value");
conf.save();
```

Comment: This is much better answer than the accepted one

Comment: @José Mª I downloaded https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/index.html ApacheCommons Configurator 2.1.1 and it seems that  `save()` method and some others doesn't exists . Is there any alternative ?

Comment: @GOXR3PLUS Please check this website: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide_v1.10/howto_properties.html

There is a "Saving" section where its explained.

Comment: @José Mª Thanks for the link . It seems to be only for the version 1.10 , not for the version 2.1.1 which is the latest :) . I am searching inside https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/user_guide.html to find something similar .

Comment: @GOXR3PLUS Sorry I can't test it right now, but I thought it should work because there is a annotation at the header of the website where you can see: "Last Published: 08 February 2017|Version: 2.1.1"
It's quite confusing, but you can still use older versions. Unfortunately, I cannot help you any more with this :(

Comment: @JoséMª
I had used the 1.1 version.
Also, the 2.1 version has the `save()` method in it.
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration2/PropertiesConfiguration.html

Comment: @AnirbanDebnath Thank you for the info, but how can that link demonstrate it? There are only 1 match with "`save()`" in the whole page and doesn't correspond to the method description. Where is `save()` hidden?

Comment: Okay you are using the apache-commons thats causing the issue.
Use the commons-configuration one.
Use this:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.9

Comment: I am using commons configuration2 but getting an error when using above code `PropertiesConfiguration() in PropertiesConfiguration can not be applied to (java.lang.String)

Comment: Hi @J.Doem: You can use the Older `1.10 version` which has a String args constructor to pass the file name directly. Else, for V2, you can use the `PropertyConfiguration` class's `loadIncludeFile(String fileName)` method to pass the File name.

Comment: This solution solved my 2 issues.
1. Saving the file without losing other data and also
2. Keys positions are not swapped (By using other solutions i.e., with FileInput & Output streams, positions of keys are getting swapped to random positions and also comments are getting removed).

Answer (score 10):

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(...); // FileInputStream 
prop.setProperty("key", "value");
prop.store(...); // FileOutputStream
```