# How do I update a properties value in java without deleting other variables

Tags: java, variables, properties

**Content of data.txt file**

```
pin=9876

balance=9001

investment=10000

interest=0.065

isLockedOut=false
```

---

My code currently:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Properties;

public class SetData extends ATM {

    public static void setIsLockedOut(boolean isLockedOut) { //Sets the isLockedOut variable
        try {
            Properties data = new Properties();   
            FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("data.txt");
            if (isLockedOut = true) {
                data.setProperty("isLockedOut", "true");
                data.store(output, null);
                output.close(); //Closes the output stream
            }
            else {
                data.setProperty("isLockedOut", "false");
                data.store(output, null);
                output.close();
            }     
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I have also checked and referred to a similar question on StackOverflow as well ([Updating property value in properties file without deleting other values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15337409/how-to-update-property-value-in-properties-file-using-java)).

The method 'setIsLockedOut' is called from another class. 
When I call this method to set the 'isLockedOut' variable to true in the 'data.txt' file, all other variables are erased except the 'isLockedOut' variable. This is the output:

```
#Sun Nov 17 15:44:42 EST 2013

isLockedOut=true
```

So my question is, how can I update a property value without erasing the other values in the file?

Comment: You have to load all the properties, update the one you want, THEN save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you are doing is overwriting the data.txt file with the content of `data` which is just the value of "isLockedOut". It seems that what you want to do is to overwrite data.txt with all of the properties that used to be in data.txt, plus an updated value for "isLockedOut". To do that, you need to open data.txt for reading and read its content into `data`, then modify `data`, then overwrite data.txt with the new `data`. Skipping the first step is what is causing your problem.

You need to use a `FileInputStream` and the [`load` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29). Use them much the same way you are using `FileOutputStream` and `store` already.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I used the FileInputStream and the load method, however the problem still exists. What am I doing wrong here? Here is the updated code: http://pastebin.com/fBXKr08T

Comment: @reconwhale, it's a bit strange to have the file open for both reading and writing at the same time. That might cause problems. Do the reading, close the file, then open it for writing. Also, I don't think `if(isLockedOut = true)` does what you think it does.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working perfectly now! Fixed code for future readers: http://pastebin.com/7TbDiHre