# How to write values in a properties file through java code

Tags: java

I have an issue.

I have a properties file. I want to store some values in that file and will implement in the code whenever it is required.  Is there any way to do that?

I am using `Properties` class to do that..

Comment: Have you looked at the Javadoc for the `Properties` class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to update property value in properties file using java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15337409/how-to-update-property-value-in-properties-file-using-java)

Comment: There are _Files_ (on the file system) and there are _resources_ on the class path. For writing you should opt for the file system, not in the application jar.

Answer (score 45):

Load the properties file using [`java.util.Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html).

Code snippet -

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("xyz.properties");
prop.load(in);
```

It provides [`Properties#setProperty(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) which helps to add new property.

Code snippet -

```
prop.setProperty("newkey", "newvalue");
```

This new set you can save using [`Properties#store(java.io.OutputStream, java.lang.String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String%29)

Code Snippet -

```
prop.store(new FileOutputStream("xyz.properties"), null);
```

Comment: Thanks for editing and making the the answer more meaningful @Jason C

Comment: Are the files `xyz.properties` in both cases (InputStream and FileOutputStream) the same here?

Comment: yap it is same for both cases.

Comment: For me (in a war) it worked with 'getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream'    instead of 'getClass().getResourceAsStream'

Comment: this is a bad idea , since it will mess up the encoding

Answer (score 11):

You can do it in following way:

1. Set the properties first in the `Properties` object by using `object.setProperty(String obj1, String obj2)`.
2. Then write it to your `File` by passing a `FileOutputStream` to `properties_object.store(FileOutputStream, String)`.

Here is the example code :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.File;

class Main
{
    static File file;
    static void saveProperties(Properties p) throws IOException
    {
        FileOutputStream fr = new FileOutputStream(file);
        p.store(fr, "Properties");
        fr.close();
        System.out.println("After saving properties: " + p);
    }

    static void loadProperties(Properties p)throws IOException
    {
        FileInputStream fi=new FileInputStream(file);
        p.load(fi);
        fi.close();
        System.out.println("After Loading properties: " + p);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)throws IOException
    {
        file = new File("property.dat");
        Properties table = new Properties();
        table.setProperty("Shivam","Bane");
        table.setProperty("CS","Maverick");
        System.out.println("Properties has been set in HashTable: " + table);
        // saving the properties in file
        saveProperties(table);
        // changing the property
        table.setProperty("Shivam", "Swagger");
        System.out.println("After the change in HashTable: " + table);
        // saving the properties in file
        saveProperties(table);
        // loading the saved properties
        loadProperties(table);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error message : "Resource is out of sync with the file system: 'xyz.properties'." and also how to delete the file my job is over... And while retrieving the value the values are null...I am wondering what might be the issue?

Comment: For "Resources is out of syn" check [**link**](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_When_should_I_use_refreshLocal%3F).For deleting simple use delete function **file.delete()**.

Comment: this saves into the properties file but removes the existence data from file.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is not clear since Writing/reading from properties files is something already available in java.

To write to properties file you can use the Properties class as you mentioned :

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
try(OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(PROPERTIES_FILE_PATH)){  
    properties.setProperty("prop1", "Value1");
    properties.setProperty("prop2", "Value2");
    properties.store(outputStream, null);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

[Source and more examples here](https://tutoref.com/how-to-read-and-write-properties-file/)

Answer (score 2):

This work for me.

```
    Properties prop = new Properties();

                try {
                        InputStream in = new FileInputStream("src/loop.properties");
                        prop.load(in);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                       System.out.println(ex);
                    }
           //Setting the value to  our properties file.
           prop.setProperty("LOOP", "1");
           //Getting the value from  our properties file.
           String value = prop.getProperty("LOOP").trim();

                try {
                        prop.store(new FileOutputStream("src/loop.properties"), null);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                       System.out.println(ex);
                    }
```