# Codename One and Java save / update properties value in file

Tags: java, codenameone

There are several examples in Java about how to save a value in a properties file - for example:

[How to write values in a properties file through java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22370051/how-to-write-values-in-a-properties-file-through-java-code)

https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

You will notice that they all use the "import java.io.FileOutputStream" code, however when I try and use the same code I get this error ....

```
error: cannot find symbol
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
symbol:   class FileOutputStream
location: package java.io
```

I believe that this is a standard Java library and should be available right? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Have you added JRE to your classpath? Looks like class is unable to find class FileOutputStream

Comment: Thanks for the advice - but wouldn't this then fail for every import? Why is is just this one?

Comment: This is just an assumption because program is failing at importing Class. If you can paste your program it would be easier to analyze.

Answer (score 2):

Codename One doesn't support full Java API (The Standard Libraries) and here is why... **[Why we don't support the full Java API](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/why-we-dont-support-the-full-java-api.html)**.

If you need the Properties Object, read about it **[in this blog](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/properties.html).**

Codename One has another properties file which is used to guide your app building process, and you can add some data that Codename One supports by Right-clicking your project, Going to Properties, switching to Build Hint Tab and entering the key-value pair there.

Comment: Thank you for this. I browsed to this location in the documentation 

https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/Properties.html#setProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

And it talks about the setProperty() function being able to update a value. However when I use it the value doesn't change. Here is my code ...

switch (evt.getCommand().toString())
{
   case "SaveValue":
       try{
          valueProperties.setProperty("current_Value", txtValue.getText());
          txtValue.setEditable(false);
            }

Comment: Ahhh I've just realised that the setProperty() function only changes the running value of the property - it doesn't actually save it back to the file. I need to figure out how to do that. Ok Ok we're getting somewhere now :-)

Comment: That's the same behavior as JavaSE you can use Properties.store() to save the file. However, Codename One has a better approach that's more seamless than JavaSE to store a simple variable: `Preferences`. Use `String val = Preferences.get("MyVariableName", defaultValue);` and `Preferences.set("MyVariableName", actualValue);`