# how to read a file from resources folder in properties file

Tags: java, spring-mvc, properties-file

I have a file under resources folder `src/test/resources/file.xml`
and another under `src/test/resources/test.properties`. I want to set a property in properties file to point to `file.xml`. How can I achieve this?

Say I have a property

```
test.file = file.xml
```

and my java class reads the file as follows:

```
File cert = new File(fileName); // fileName is the value of test.file
```

This does not work however.

Comment: It's not quite clear what the issue is. What error are you getting?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22370051/how-to-write-values-in-a-properties-file-through-java-code

Comment: You need either a full path or a `URI` instance to create an instance of [`File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html).

Comment: @question_tech you need to use the relative  path to get the full name. Please check my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class to read and write to config files.

Answer (score 1):

- Firstly, you need to find the relative path for the resources using
  below steps
- Secondly, you can configure and load the test properties file
- Finally, read the property value and append with the resource
  directory

**Code:**

```
String rootDirectory=System.getProperty("user.dir");
String resourceDirectory=rootDirectory+"src/test/resources/";

//Configure property File
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new FileInputStream(resourceDirectory+"test.properties"));
PropertyConfigurator.configure(properties);

//To get the property value
String tempFileName=properties.getProperty("test.file");

//filename Needs to be changed as below
File cert = new File(resourceDirectory+tempFileName);
```