# How to read string from .properties File

Tags: java, spring

I needed some configuration file. So I created a config.properties in resources. Is that the best way to do it ? It looks quite heavy. But maybe better than accessing a database.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();

try 
{
    File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:config.properties");
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
    properties.load(in);
    String maxHolidays = (String) properties.get("maxHolidays");
    properties.setProperty("maxHolidays", "20");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("");
}
```

if I want to set a new value to my property "maxHolidays"  is it also possible from code

Comment: Note that your code assumes this is a file on disk.

Comment: There are easier ways to get those values, look at e.g. `@Value`.

Comment: I just put the file in resources folder. Should not give error when I let it run in live mode on server

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write values in a properties file through java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22370051/how-to-write-values-in-a-properties-file-through-java-code)

Comment: if I get the file by using getFile("classpath:config.properties")   Class path, could that be a problem if I not use an IDE but just pure virtual machine. Do I provide this paramater to vm ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use properties and read values:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
public class ExampleConfig {

    @Value("${maxHolidays}")
    private String maxHolidays;

    public String getMaxHolidays() {
        return maxHolidays;
    }
}
```

You then can `@Autowire` that config into any component, and read the value of `maxHolidays`.

```
if I want to set a new value to my property "maxHolidays" is it also possible from code
```

If the change is *transient*, you can add a setter as well.

If you intend to *persist* the change back to the properties, you can no longer use them as a classpath resource (as this resource usually gets bundled into your JAR), but need file-based properties - in that case, use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html, which provide `load` and `store` methods.

Comment: Where should I put the ExampleConfig class ?   Yes I want to persist the value. It should be persisted in the .properties file. Ah ok. If I want to persist it I cannot use the path as I did in my code, but instead have to use src/main/resources/config.properties and not classpath: