# replace properties of properties file

Tags: java

I have a `cluster.properties` file with contents :

```
master=1.2
first.node=
second.node=10.20.30.30
```

I want to replace these properties with some different value. How can I do this this?

My method look like `replaceProp(String filePath, String prop, String newValue)`

Comment: Do you know how to actually read and write to a file? It should be easy if you do. If you don't, there are countless tutorials/SO questions one Google search away...

Comment: Thanks! I got some answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15337409/updating-property-value-in-properties-file-without-deleting-other-values

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this could be:

Read Properties:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("cluster.properties");
properties.load(fis);
fis.close();
```

Replace:

```
properties.set("master", "1.2.3")
...
```

Save back:

```
FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("cluster.properties");
properties.store(fos,"Some meaningfule comments");
fos.close();
```

Comment: Closing streams should be done in a finally block/ try-with-resources statement.